# Python Drag & Drop Programming

Tags: python, drag-and-drop

I am working on creating software that runs some bioinstrumentation hardware. One of my colleagues thought it would be a benefit if we could program certain operation sequences via a drag-and-drop interface, something LabVIEW-style that would be able to execute callbacks in custom orders.

**I am not looking for a GUI designer.** I already use PyQt5 & Qt Designer to create interfaces. I want an interface that will allow me to use my functions to create custom scripts graphically.

The system we are using is built to run with a Raspberry Pi as the main controller, so softwares like LABView itself are not viable. The entire application is written in Python (with the flexibility for certain extensions as needed).

How can I achieve this? My searching thus far hasn't yielded any useful results.

Comment: Why not just use LabVIEW?

Comment: I'm trying to stay within the confines of entirely free software, usable from a Raspberry Pi. The system was designed the way it was to avoid using software like LabVIEW. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: I think this is going to be too broad as a question. It doesn't sound simple to implement

Comment: Fair enough- but some suggestions as per libraries/applications I could use would be great.

Comment: Then that definitely qualifies as off-topic sorry. Recommendations for libraries is specifically off-topic.

Comment: I'll close the question then. I apologize for being off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like Google's blockly https://developers.google.com/blockly/? I'm not sure compatible with Raspberry Pi but may be worth looking into.